# How to setup Atom 1.0 feed?

Tags: html, xml, url, atom-feed

I'm brand new to Atom feeds. I'd like to set-up a basic feed. What url do I create (and call from my app?). How many documents do I need for my feed? Perhaps just the document containing xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

        <title>Example Feed</title>
        <subtitle>A subtitle.</subtitle>
        <link href="http://example.org/feed/" rel="self" />
        <link href="http://example.org/" />
        <id>urn:uuid:60a76c80-d399-11d9-b91C-0003939e0af6</id>
        <updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated>
        <author>
                <name>John Doe</name>
                <email>johndoe@example.com</email>
        </author>

        <entry>
                <title>Atom-Powered Robots Run Amok</title>
                <link href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03" />
                <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03.html"/>
                <link rel="edit" href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03/edit"/>
                <id>urn:uuid:1225c695-cfb8-4ebb-aaaa-80da344efa6a</id>
                <updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated>
                <summary>Some text.</summary>
        </entry>

</feed>
```

Do I need an additional html document that references the document containing the xml data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question :

> just the document containing xml like this

Syndication feeds are XML data. You can implement them statically (XML file) or dynamically (for example, a PHP script that returns a XML string).

Go on, you're on the right track.